# How to access to a kubenetes pod from outside using proxmox(Virtualisation solution)

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, kubernetes, proxmox

I have a proxmox host(@ip=231.25.36.12),inside I have installed a kubernetes cluseter, this cluster consists of 3 vms(these VMs are not routable I mean they are accessible just from proxmox node, they are not accessble from outside):

k8s-ctrlr 192.168.1.2
k8s-node-01 192.168.1.3
k8s-node-02 192.168.1.4

to access to the master node(k8s-ctrlr), I need first ssh to proxmox host then I need to do another ssh to the master node(192.168.1.2).
so I create a pod (nginx) to test my cluster and here’s the result(see picture pod-1) :

as you see the nginx is running as expected inside the master-node(pod-1 image) and also from proxmox host(pod-2 image).

but the problem when I try to access it from the browser it doesnt work (nav-2 image): (30080 is nodePort service)
[image]

so now my question , is there any solution to access the nginx application using @ip of the master node, or proxmox @ip ? our goal is to be able to access the app from the browser.
Could help us please ?

thanks for you help